# Connect with IBM terminal using Micro Focus Reflection

Tags: emulation

I have to connect IBM terminal through Micro Focus Reflection using C#, but unable to find any code for this except

[Micro Focus Reflection Desktop](http://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/16-1-1/net-prog-guide/#create-a-new-session.html)

But this is also not working. In this I have to add reffrences to 

using Attachmate Reflection Framework

using Attachmate Reflection Emulation IbmHosts

using Attachmate Reflection UserInterface

namespaces. But these namespaces are not available there in Com,Assemblies or any other tab. 
Please help me in this

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Not getting any error but when i search Attachmate.Reflection in Add reffrence dialog box under Com tab. It shows "No Items found."